# fsockopen return value false or true

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$check1 = fsockopen("111.222.333.444","8080"); 

if ($check1) { 
  echo ("true"); 
  $close = fclose($check1); 
} 
else 
  echo ("false");
```

How do I get it back to me this value true and false in a string?
Example:

```
if($check1 == "false") {

    // Conecct SSH

if($check1 == "true") {

    // Not connect SSH
```

Comment: What's the point of having true and false in a string for same comparison? Your first if block is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more parameters:

```
$check1 = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);
        if (!$check1) { // $check1==false
            echo $errno . ' ' . $errstr
        } else { // $check1==true
             //Your code
        }
```